# Postgresql :: operation select sysdate didn`t work

Tags: postgresql

I recently installed postgres v15 in windows 10 machine and below paths set to system variables >> Path

- C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\lib
- C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin

When I run `SELECT SYSDATE;` or `SELECT VERSION;` on query editor tool of PGAdmin I`m getting below error

```
ERROR:  column "sysdate" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SYSDATE;
               ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 8
```

**Note** : Table creation or SELECT of PG tables all working fine.

Answer (score 0):

`SYSDATE` is from Oracle not Postgresql. You should use `CURRENT_DATE`.

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE;
```

Source: [Converting the SYSDATE function from Oracle to PostgreSQL](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/converting-the-sysdate-function-from-oracle-to-postgresql/)

Answer (score 0):

`SYSDATE` is an Oracle-only function.

The ANSI standard defines `current_date` or `current_timestamp` which
**is** supported by PostgreSQL and documented in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT